# Multiply every form value in Django template using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm created a form where values are coming from my `view` and the value is `daily basis` and I want to give a drop down where user can change it to weekly basis and the values will be multiplied by 7.

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, I'm giving a drop down option where user can change it to `weekly basis` and `monthly basis` and the value inside the form will change as per the selection. But I'm not aware how I can achieve this.

My code:

```
return render(request, 'test.html',
                      {'List1': l1, 'List2': l2, 'List3': l3}
```

and my form.html is readonly form which renders these `list` in order.

```
                        <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            {% for l in List1 %}
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label>x</label>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" value="{{l}}" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </div>
                      ........simliary for rest list.
                    </form>
```

I want to multiply every value inside form by 7 when user selects weekly in drop-down. How can I achieve it?

Comment: do you want to multiply **{{l}}** ??

Comment: yes when the user changes to weekly

Comment: javascript will help you

Comment: How can I do it for whole form